# React component will mount is not getting called

Tags: reactjs

I have been working on a chat application using react and websockets, My problem is the method

> componetWillUnmount()
>   doesn't get called when the state changes and component re-renders.

I have been trying to add 'li' elements to my chatArea component for every new message coming in a chat, and as soon as I am selecting another chat, I want to remove all those 'li' elements that were rendered in previous chat, for that I have tried 2 things, one to remove all child of  or I am changing the state. But componentWillUnmount is not getting called. And i am not able to remove li elements.

Below is my code

```
import React from 'react'

export default class ChatArea extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      currentUser: this.props.currentUser,
      selectedUser: this.props.selectedUser,
      messages: []
    }
    this.handleMessage = this.handleMessage.bind(this)
  }

  handleMessage (obj) {
    let messages = this.state.messages
    messages.push(obj)
    this.setState({
      messages: messages
    })
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    window.socket.on('show message', obj => {
      this.handleMessage(obj)
    })
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    window.socket.emit('join', {
      sender: this.state.currentUser,
      receiver: this.state.selectedUser
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    console.log('something')
    const chatList = this.refs.chatList
    while (chatList.hasChildNodes()) {
      console.log('removing children', chatList.lastChild)
      chatList.removeChild(chatList.lastChild)
    }
orrrrrrrrrrrrrr
      this.setState({
        messages: []
      })
  }

  render () {
    console.log('chatARea state', this.state)
    let messages = this.state.messages
    let i = 0
    return (
      <div className='row chat-area'>
        <ul className='col m12' ref='chatList'>
          {messages.map(msg => <li key={i++}>{msg.sentBy.firstname + ': ' + msg.message}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

module.exports = ChatArea
```

Comment: componentWillUnmount will get triggered only when ChatArea component in going to unmount.

Comment: componentWillUnmount will mostly likely be called when you are changing state from your chat window which doesn't have messages list. Any way you shouldn't remove nodes this way. Let react handle it - just change your messages object based on the view you are in and render respective chat

Comment: BTW you usually need to remove listeners and other stuff and not nodes in componentWillUnmount.

Comment: componentWillUnmount() is invoked immediately before a component is unmounted and destroyed. Perform any necessary cleanup in this method, such as invalidating timers, canceling network requests, or cleaning up any DOM elements that were created in componentDidMount

Comment: @Sudheer below is my constructor for this component

`constructor (props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
        currentUser: this.props.currentUser,
        selectedUser: this.props.selectedUser,
        messages: []
      }
      this.handleMessage = this.handleMessage.bind(this)
    }`
so every-time i get new props the state changes and the component renders again, at this time I want to clear out messages[], so that it wont appear in the other chat message window

Comment: This is not all your code, this is missing the class where the ChatArea is actually used. If you are expecting this to unmount, whatever problem there is will be there in the code we cannot see.

Comment: @AishwaryaChaturvedi are you saying you are clearing out because you don't want to see the earlier conversation in a different window? Then you would have to emit an event to change view in all open instances than doing it based on clearing messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out the answer of my own question, the state of the component was not getting changed, so the method componentWillMount() was not getting called.

Thanks everyone for the help